# Show that $Res_{z = z_0}(f(z)g(z)) = g(z_0)Res_{z = z_0}(f(z))$ for a function with the following characteristics

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that a function $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ and $g$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, show the following:

$Res_{z = z_0}(f(z)g(z)) = g(z_0)Res_{z = z_0}(f(z))$

The residue is the coefficient of the term $z^{-1}$ but I'm having trouble formally writing the steps, and I'm not sure if what I want to do is correct in the first place.

Comment: Residue is coefficient of the term $\frac {1} {(z-z_0)}$ not $z^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $fg$ is holomorphic in a punctured disk around $z_0$, and as $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$, $Res_{z = z_0} f(z) = \lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) f(z) = c \in \Bbb C^*$.

Now:

$$\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) f(z) g(z) =  g(z_0) \lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z) = g(z_0) c = \begin{cases} 0&\text{if }g(z_0) = 0 \\ g(z_0) c \neq 0&\text{if } g(z_0) \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

If it is the first case, then $fg$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ and $Res_{z = z_0} f(z)g(z) = 0 = g(z_0) Res_{z = z_0} f(z)$

If it's the second case, then $fg$ has a simple pole at $z_0$, and:

$Res_{z = z_0} f(z)g(z) = \lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0) f(z) g(z) = g(z_0) c = g(z_0) Res_{z=z_0}f(z)$

Answer (score 0):

Write down the power series around $z_0$. Collect the coefficient of $\dfrac{1}{z-z_0}$. Does that help?